# Pantheon-files just can't remember my samba password

Tags: pantheon-files, samba

I have to input the username and password everytime I use the samba service.

If I close the pantheon-files at the samba directory, the next time I open it, it will ask for my password twice, it is so annoying.

Comment: This looks to be an in-progress bug that the Elementary team is aware of.  https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files/+bug/1433213

Answer (score 1):

If you are comfortable using the command line, the advice here will help you:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently

Basically, you need to create an entry in /etc/fstab that will try to mount your drive with password provided automatically.

Perhaps there is a way the GUI could be improved, but in the short term this should solve your problem (if you are regularly away from the share's network, it will cause a failed mount, but I think that is OK so long as you don't make any system stuff dependent)